SharePoint Graph API delivering empty value in drive items query with filter on a folder
I am trying to get the drive item id of a SharePoint folder which I need so I can upload a file to the folder. For one SharePoint site this works fine, but for another site the returned value is always empty. Does anybody know, why this happens?
my graph api get request has the form
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drives/{drive-id}/Items?$filter= Name eq '{foldername}'

where site-id and drive-id are the ids I retrieved with earlier inquires.
On the SharePoint site where it works I get an answer like this from which I need the returned id:
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites('{site-id}')/drives('{drive-id}')/items",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.etag": "\"{guid},2\"",
            "createdDateTime": "2024-09-02T12:41:17Z",
            "eTag": "\"{guid},2\"",
            "id": "{driveitemid}",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2024-09-02T12:41:19Z",
            "name": "{name-of-my-folder}",
            "size": 1424250,
            "webUrl": "{site-url}/CRM/{url-encoded-folder name}",
            "cTag": "\"c:{guid},0\"",
            "title": "{folder name}",
            "createdBy": {
                ...
            },
            "lastModifiedBy": {
                ...
            },
            "parentReference": {
                "driveId": "{drive-id}",
                "driveType": "documentLibrary",
                "id": "{some other id}",
                "path": "/drives/{drive-id}/root:",
                "sharepointIds": {
                    "listId": "{list-id}",
                    "listItemUniqueId": "...",
                    "siteId": "{site-id}",
                    "siteUrl": "{site-url}",
                    "tenantId": "...",
                    "webId": "..."
                }
            },
            "commentSettings": {
                "commentingDisabled": {
                    "isDisabled": false
                }
            },
            "fileSystemInfo": {
                "createdDateTime": "2024-09-02T12:41:17Z",
                "lastModifiedDateTime": "2024-09-02T12:41:19Z"
            },
            "folder": {
                "childCount": 7,
                "view": {}
            },
            "shared": {
                ...
            }
        }
    ],
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drives/{drive-id}/Items?$filter=name+eq+foldername&$skiptoken=..."
}

On the site where it does not work, the value is just empty and the response looks like this:
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites('{site-id2}')/drives('{}drive-id2')/items",
    "value": [],
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id2}/drives/{drive-id2}/Items?$filter=name+eq+foldername2"
}

Is there a SharePoint setting that is necessary for this to work, that is not set on the 2nd site?
The obvious pit falls have been checked: the folder exists and there is no typo in the name of the folder.

The API only queries certain number of items, when when no results are found in those items, it returns a nextLink for you to query the next page of items.
Keep querying the nextLink provided in the results until it is no longer returned.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging?tabs=http
